# Auto-Selecting the Displayed Text of a Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6, anchor, textselection

How can I auto-select the displayed text of a hyperlink upon hover?

```
let aryAnchors = [... document.getElementsByTagName("a")];
for(a of aryAnchors)
{
    a.addEventListener("mouseover",function()
    {
        // What goes here?
    });
}
```

or, if this can be done in CSS3, that would be even better.

**Some background (if you wish):**

I have a page where users often want to copy the displayed text of hyper-links into their clipboard by highlight it and hitting control-C (but there are other shortcut keys they have set up that do other things to selected text beyond just copying it to their clipboard).

Manually highlighting around a hyperlink (without clicking it, or without copying white-space on either end of your selection) is cumbersome.

Without using browser extensions, I want the displayed text of a hyperlink to become selected on hover, so that all the user has to do is hover over the hyperlink and then hit ctrl-C (as an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by CSS. You need JavaScript here.

Use the [`selectNodeContents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents) of the `range` interface to set the contents of a node to the range. Then add it to the `selection` object.

**Here is a crude demo snippet**:

```js
function select(elem) {
  var range, selection;    
  selection = window.getSelection(); 
  range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(elem);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}
function deselect() {
  var selection = window.getSelection(); 
  selection.removeAllRanges();
}

document.addEventListener('mouseover', textselection);
document.addEventListener('mouseout', textdeselection);

function textselection(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') { select(e.target); }
}
function textdeselection(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'A') { deselect(); }
}
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding:0; margin: 0; font-family: sans-serif;  }
a { margin: 8px; }
p, ul, hr { margin: 8px; }
```

```html
<p>Below is a list of links which you can select by hovering over. You need to first focus the page by clicking anywhere on the document.</p>
<div>
  <a href="#">Link one</a>
  <a href="#">Link two</a>
  <a href="#">Link three</a>
</div>
<hr>
<p>Below is a list which you cannot select by hovering over.</p>
<ul><li>List Item 1</li><li>List Item 2</li><li>List Item 3</li></ul>
```

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/826qh1fn/

Comment: Although your code definitely highlights the links, hitting ctrl-c does not copy that which is highlighted (nor does right-click > copy).

Comment: @LonnieBest it does. I tested it before posting. You need to focus the page. Click anywhere on the document once. Then you should be able to see the blue highlight. Otherwise it will just show a grey highlight. It needs focus on the page.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, you called your demo "crude", but I see nothing crude about it. It's good code. It even works for dynamically created hyperlinks that are not even in the dom at the time of page load. Good job.

Comment: Thanks @LonnieBest for the kind words. I called it crude because I typed it quickly for this answer and did not check for edge cases, exceptions, and cross browser and the usual sanity checks. It is minimal and works in major browsers. That's where I stopped. Am sure you will work around that. Yeah, it works for dynamic elements because I used event delegation (its in my habit), i.e. event handlers on highest possible parent and using `e.target`.

Comment: I just saw this post again after a long while. The practice of putting event handlers on the highest possible parent, is one I learned from you. It has served me well. Thanks again!